# mysql convert_tz not working in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a `datetime` field and am trying to use `CONVERT_TZ` to look `BETWEEN` dates.  Here's an example just selecting:

```
SELECT (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`created_at`,'+00:00','+05:00'), ' %Y-%m-%d')) FROM `pages`
```

This works fine and returns results.  However, when I try to use this in a `WHERE` clause that should return results:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `pages`
WHERE
    (DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(`created_at`, '+00:00', '+05:00'),
            '%Y-%m-%d')) BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-30'
```

This doesn't return anything.    But those between dates, there are many many records that should validate between those.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySQL at hands right now. Having said this, I just would like to help with a few quick hints:

1) [`DATE_FORMAT` returns a string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format), and you are comparing strings in your `WHERE` clause. From your reputation, I am absolutely sure that you know that comparing numbers (or other numeric types) as strings is not the wisest thing in some cases :-).

2) If you would like to compare date-times taking time zones into account, you eventually should use constants which are designating a time zone as well (in your case, the hard-coded lower end and upper end of the interval in question). At least, that would be consistent and easy to understand for somebody else.

3) Please be aware that a [`TIMESTAMP` field in MySQL converts data being inserted to UTC, taking the current time zone into account, and does the opposite process with data being read, while a `DATETIME` field does not do that](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) (you did not mention the type of the fields involved). This might lead to unexpected results with `TIMESTAMP` fields.

For that reason, I never have used `TIMESTAMP` fields (I am doing the time zone conversions, which usually are associated with locale conversions anyway, in the back-end code or client code, at least outside the database software). Because of this, I don't know how MySQL behaves if you compare `TIMESTAMP` fields. Does it first pull the value out of the field, thereby converting it from UTC to the current time zone, and then does the comparison, or does it perform the comparison based on the raw (UTC) data stored in the field?

As a final note, your `SELECT` statement of course also returns the date-times as strings, but in this case, you won't notice since you are only viewing them, but are not doing calculations (or comparisons) with them.